# I live in NJ. Do I need a p-trap and vent on a washer drain line not going directly to the stack?

Tags: washing-machine, drainage, laundry

[image]Here is my situation.  As it sits now, my washer drains directly into the slop sink right next to it.

I live in a split level and I am moving the washer & Dryer up one half level about 6 feet in height from the original location on the basement level up to the ground floor level.  My plan is to set up a PVC drain standpipe for the Washer to travel to the first elbow underneath the washer utilizing the correct sloping and traveling 4 feet across and through the wall into the basement to the second elbow.  From there it would be using the correct sloping again and traveling 9 ft to a 3rd elbow and then a foot and a half back into the slop sink.

I am not tapping this into the stack, so do I still need a p-trap, and also a vent?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. A diagram or photo would make this a lot easier to understand.

Comment: I added an image for you @DanielGriscom.

Comment: Excellent. Now it's time for one of our plumbers to comment.